# ffmpegのmakeでのエラーついて

Tags: ffmpeg, raspbian

ffmpegでx264を使いたくて、libx264をいれてmakeしたら`make: *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 1`というエラーがでました。
他の方も`ffmpeg_g Error 1`がでたという人がいてその方の質問には「このライブラリがリンクしようとしているライブラリのバージョンの不一致なのでは？」と答えられていました。
もしライブラリのバージョンが不一致の場合どのようにすればエラーはなくなりますか？
makeの結果は

```
LD  ffmpeg_g
libavformat/libavformat.a(rtsp.o): In function `ff_rtsp_connect':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavformat/rtsp.c:1659: undefined reference to `ff_log2_tab'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(asvdec.o): In function `asv2_get_level':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/asvdec.c:92: undefined reference to `ff_reverse'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(asvdec.o): In function `decode_frame':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/asvdec.c:267: undefined reference to `ff_reverse'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(asvenc.o): In function `encode_mb':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/asvenc.c:177: undefined reference to `ff_reverse'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(asvenc.o): In function `encode_frame':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/asvenc.c:304: undefined reference to `ff_reverse'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(dsddec.o): In function `decode_frame':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/dsddec.c:150: undefined reference to `ff_reverse'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(ivi.o):/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/ivi.c:162: more undefined references to `ff_reverse' follow
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(tiertexseqv.o): In function `seqvideo_decode':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/tiertexseqv.c:191: undefined reference to `ff_log2_tab'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(tiff.o): In function `deinvert_buffer':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/tiff.c:282: undefined reference to `ff_reverse'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(webp.o): In function `webp_get_vlc':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/webp.c:263: undefined reference to `ff_reverse'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(wnv1.o): In function `decode_frame':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/wnv1.c:79: undefined reference to `ff_reverse'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(xsubdec.o): In function `decode_frame':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/xsubdec.c:102: undefined reference to `ff_log2_tab'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(xsubenc.o): In function `put_bits':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/put_bits.h:182: undefined reference to `ff_log2_tab'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(xsubenc.o): In function `xsub_encode_rle':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/xsubenc.c:91: undefined reference to `ff_log2_tab'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(aacps_fixed.o): In function `get_bits':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/get_bits.h:268: undefined reference to `ff_log2_tab'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(aacps_float.o): In function `get_bits':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/get_bits.h:268: undefined reference to `ff_log2_tab'
libavformat/libavformat.a(matroskadec.o):/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavformat/matroskadec.c:746: more undefined references to `ff_log2_tab' follow
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(bitstream.o): In function `alloc_table':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/bitstream.c:115: undefined reference to `ff_reverse'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(bitstream.o): In function `ff_init_vlc_sparse':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/bitstream.c:288: undefined reference to `ff_reverse'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(dcaenc.o): In function `calc_masking':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/dcaenc.c:530: undefined reference to `ff_reverse'
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/dcaenc.c:530: undefined reference to `ff_reverse'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(s302m.o): In function `s302m_decode_frame':
/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/s302m.c:190: undefined reference to `ff_reverse'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(xbmdec.o):/home/pi/ffmpeg/libavcodec/xbmdec.c:127: more undefined references to `ff_reverse' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'ffmpeg_g' failed
make: *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 1
```

このようになりました。`undefined references to` という表示が何カ所もでていますが、これはmakeできていないんですよね？
この場合の対処法を教えて欲しいです。よろしくお願いします。
私が使っているLinuxはRaspbianです。
行った処理は
x264を使いたかったので

```
git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=PREFIX
make & make install
```

この後に

```
git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libx264
make
```

この最後のmakeで`make: * [ffmpeg_g] Error 1`がでました。

Comment: あてずっぽうですが、 `sudo ./configure --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libx264` `make clean` `make`   だとどうなりますか？

Comment: ちなみに、`ff_log2_tab` と `ff_reverse` はそれぞれ `ffmpeg/libavutil/log2_tab.c` と `ffmpeg/libavutil/reverse.c` にありますので、`ffmpeg/libavutil/libavutil.a` がリンクされていないのかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

ffmpegをRaspbianに入れるにはToolchainが必要で、
Toolchainを入れるにはcrosstool-ng が必要なようです。

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/RaspberryPi

Comment: そうなんですか！？
その記事は初めてみます、、、
直接Raspbianにffmpegをインストールするという記事がなかなかなかったのでそれを参考にやってみます！