# Illegal instructionというエラーについて

Tags: raspberry-pi, ffmpeg, raspbian

過去に[ffmpegの`make`について質問しました。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/17376/ffmpeg%E3%81%AEmake%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)
そこで頂いた回答を元に、ffmpegの`./configure`に`--extra-cflags='-march=armv6' --extra-ldflags='-march=armv6'`を指定して`make`しました。

そのffmpegを使って、
`ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -threads 2 -codec:v libx264 -s:v 1280x720 -aspect:v 16:9 -b:v 256k -map 0 -f segment -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10 -segment_list stream.m3u8 streamfiles/stream%03d.ts`
としたところ、`Illegal instruction`というエラーが出ました。
このエラーはどうやらffmpegではなくてgccからのエラーらしいのですが、どこが引っかかっているのでしょうか？

実行結果

```
ffmpeg version N-75926-gce0834b Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags='-march=armv6' --extra-ldflags='-march=armv6'
  libavutil      55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavcodec     57.  5.100 / 57.  5.100
  libavformat    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 11.100 /  6. 11.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.100
  Duration: 00:00:03.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10159 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 10156 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 2400k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Illegal instruction
```

使っている機材はRaspberry Pi B+
OSはRaspbian
です。

Comment: ・Raspbianのバージョン ・ffmpegの入手元とかバージョンとか ・調べて試してダメだった内容 あたりを書くと回答率アップ？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ここで `illegal instruction` エラーは、おそらく `libx264` の `common/arm/quant-a.S` 中にある
`rbit` 命令によって出ているのだと思われます。 `rbit` は `armv7` の命令なので
`raspberry pi 2 model B` なら実行できる (armv7) が
`raspberry pi model B+` では実行できない (armv6)
わけです。
要するに現在の `libx264` は `raspberry pi 2 model B` 向けソースとなっていて
`raspberry pi model B+` には完全自動対応でない、ってことです。
オイラが試験したのは libx264-snapshot-20151012-2245 です。

`libx264` を下記のように再構築してみてください。

```
$ make distclean (一度構築済みなら)
$ ./configure --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-asm
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

`--disable-asm` によって `quant-a.S` を使わなくなります。
もしかしたら `libx264` の `./configure` に追加オプション
`--extra-cflags='-mcpu=arm1176jzf-s' --extra-ldflags='-mcpu=arm1176jzf-s'` 
をつけると `raspberry pi model B+` により適合する機械語を生成するかもしれません。
(`raspberry pi model B+` の CPU は `arm1176jzf-s` です)

`ffmpeg` のほうに `--extra-cflags` 等は不要だと思います（つけてもかまいませんが）

さてオイラんとこでは `ffmpeg` までビルドはできたんだけどテストできる動画が無いし
そもそも `raspberry pi 2 model B` なら動いて当たり前っぽいし
これ以上は試しようがありません。ぜひ結果報告してください。

Comment: なるほど、、、さっそくやってみます！まさかlibx264のほうだったとは、、、
でもlibx264の./configureのオプションで--enable-shared --enable-staticはどちらかだけでいいのではないでしょうか？

質問にはffmpegの./configure`に`--extra-cflags='-march=armv6' --extra-ldflags='-march=armv6'を指定してやったとありますが、過去の質問ではlibx264につけてやってみてと言われていたのを間違ってやっていました、、、
libx264の方につけるとmakeの時点でエラーがでるので、つけなくてもいいのかもしれないです。

Comment: static library が要らないなら --enable-static は要らないっすよ。
libx264 に armv6 を指定すると (アセンブラ quant-a.S が armv6 非対応なので) コンパイルエラーが出ます。なので --disable-asm が必要。逆に --disable-asm なしでビルドすると armv6 上で armv7 のコードを実行しようとするので、この症状になる、んでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

`libx264`の`./configure` のオプションに`--disable-asm`を追加して再度ビルドしたところ
`ffmpeg`の`Illegal instruction`が消えました。

`--extra-cflags='-mcpu=arm1176jzf-s' --extra-ldflags='-mcpu=arm1176jzf-s`も試してみましたが体感で差分はわかりませんでした。

`raspberry pi zero`のCPUが`ARMv6`だったのを忘れてた。