# raspberry pi illegal instruction

Tags: raspberry-pi

raspberry piでyoloを動かしたく

```
sudo pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/Maratyszcza/PeachPy
sudo pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/Maratyszcza/confu

git clone https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja.git
cd ninja
git checkout release
./configure.py --bootstrap
export NINJA_PATH=$PWD

sudo apt-get install clang

git clone https://github.com/digitalbrain79/NNPACK-darknet.git
cd NNPACK-darknet
confu setup
python ./configure.py --backend auto
$NINJA_PATH/ninja
sudo cp -a lib/* /usr/lib/
sudo cp include/nnpack.h /usr/include/
sudo cp deps/pthreadpool/include/pthreadpool.h /usr/include/

git clone https://github.com/digitalbrain79/darknet-nnpack.git
cd darknet-nnpack
make
```

でサイトに書いてある通りにやってみた後に重みをDLして
./darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolo.cfg yolov2.weights data/person.jpgで実行すると
illegal insturuction
と出てしまいます。
おそらくサイトではRaspberry Pi 3を用いているのですが自分はRaspberry Pi 1Bを使っていることが原因だと思います。このエラーを直すにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？教えてくれる人がいなくて困っています(´°̥̥̥̥̥̥̥̥ω°̥̥̥̥̥̥̥̥｀)　　どうかよろしくおねがいします

Comment: make時のエラーメッセージは「illegal insturuction」だけですか？せっかくですので、エラーメッセージをコピペすると、理解してアドバイスしてくれる人が現れるかもですよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます、編集しました！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi
`Raspberry Pi` はバージョンによって CPU が違い `armv8` `armv7` `armv6` といろいろです。あなたの `Raspberry Pi 1 model B` は `armv6` のようですね。そのため `armv8` `armv7` 固有命令は実行できなくて `illegal instruction` エラーが発生します。

`armv8` 64bit なバイナリは `armv6` 上ではそもそも実行できないはずなので、実行中に `illegal instruction` が出るなら `armv7` 命令を実行しているということ。

[Illegal instructionというエラーについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/17639/)
`armv7` 専用命令を使って高速化を図っているツールやライブラリは、参考リンクに挙げた `libx264` 以外にもあるはずなので、あなたの使いたい `darknet` 本体および `darknet` が中から呼び出しているライブラリ一式のすべてが `armv6` で動くようにコンパイルされていると問題解決です。どれが `armv7` 命令を使っているかは要調査っす（オイラの手元には `Raspberry Pi 2 model B` しかないので、オイラでは調査できません）

というわけでオイラならどうするか、ですが

・野良ビルド（自分で `make` した）ツールを再ビルドしてみる
- その際に `configure` なり `Makefile` なりを読んで
--- `armv7` 固有のコンパイルオプションを指定しているか否か
--- `armv7` 固有のアセンブラファイルを使っているか否か
を調査してみる、あれば回避方法を探す

ってところでしょうか。

そういう手間をかけられないのであれば参考サイトと同じ `Raspberry Pi 3` を買っちゃうとかも大いにアリです。やりたいことでないものに悩んでいる時間がもったいないです。金で解決できる時間は、金で買っちゃえ。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！
そういうことだったんですね！！解決方法まで頂いて本当にありがとうございます
確かに時間が勿体なかったので新しく3b買っちゃいました（笑）
＼(^o^)／