# ラズパイ4(Buster)でg++ -march=armv7-aでビルドするとfilesystem?で落ちる

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, gcc

**質問**
ラズパイ4(Buster)でC++のコードを`g++ -march=armv7-a+fp`でビルドすると、filesystemを使った後でメモリ違反し落ちるようになりました。この原因と解決法を知りたいです。
今まではデフォルトで`-march=armv6+fp`が指定されていたようです。

---

**背景**
ラズパイ用のソフトをC++で開発しています。
規模が大きくなったのでクロスコンパイルや分散ビルドを使えるように環境を作りました。
それぞれでビルドした成果物は実機上で動く状態です。
現状コンパイルオプションでそれぞれ違うアーキテクチャを指定しないと動作しない状態で、それを統一したいと考えています。

| -march= | 通常・分散ビルド | クロスコンパイル |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `armv6+fp` | 動作する | コンパイルできない |
| `armv7+fp` | ビルドできるが実行すると落ちる | 動作する |

統一したい理由は
・正式なバイナリは分散ビルドを、ローカルの作業でクロスコンパイルを使用したい
・複数あるライブラリや実行ファイルの一部分をクロスコンパイルしても動くようにしたい
クロスコンパイルに統一してしまえばいいのですが、細かい動作確認ができておらず不安です

---

**環境**
本体：ラズパイ4
OS: raspios buster armhf
GCC: gcc (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0

仮想マシン
OS : rpd x86 buster
GCC: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (Debian 8.3.0-2) 8.3.0
・Windows(x64)マシン上にVirtualBoxでraspios buster(x86-64)の仮想マシンを作成
・aptでcrossbuild_essential-armhf(12.6)をインストール(gcc8.3)
・distccで分散ビルド、又はクロスコンパイル

---

**調べたこと**
落ちる箇所を調べたところ、filesystemを使用した後にメモリ違反で落ちています。
filesystemは`libstdc++fs.a`を静的リンクしており、実機とクロスで違うファイルが取り込まれています。
試しにクロスコンパイルで使用される仮想マシン上の`libstdc++fs.a`を実機上にコピーしてビルドすると、落ちないようになりました。
よって恐らく実機上の`libstdc++fs.a`はarmv6専用になっており、クロスコンパイルではarmv7専用になっているのではないかと考えています。しかし動的リンクした他のlibc等は動いており、このファイルだけというのもおかしい気がします。

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/17639/ とかを見ると `armv7` 専用命令を `armv6` CPU で動かしたら `Illegal Instruction` になる、つまりメモリ違反にはならないわけで注目点が違いそうっス。本当に `armv7` 機能を使っているかどうかは `libstdc++fs.a` を逆アセンブルでもしてみるとよいかも。

Comment: ラズパイ4のcpuは`arm8`で、OSは`armv7l`のようです。(https://www.iodata.jp/product/pc/raspberrypi/ud-rp4b/spec.htm, `arch`コマンドの出力が`armv7l`)
armv7指定でクロスコンパイルしたものは正常に動作するので、cpuやOSの問題ではないはずです。
逆アセンブルについて調べてみます。

Comment: 'armv6'の'+fp'は '+vfpv2'  を意味し, 'armv7-a'  '+fp' では '+vfpv3-d16' を意味するようですが, これは意図してのことでしょうか？ 参考: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html / Raspberry Pi 4で 32bitなら通常は `-march=armv8-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon-fp-armv8` とかでは？

Comment: 同じと思っていましたが違うようですね。fpuは別に`-mfpu=neon`で指定していました。`+fp`は余計だったかもしれません。
今までは指定していたのは`-mfpu=neon`のみで、`g++ -v`で確認すると`armv6+fp`と`-mfloat-abi=hard`が設定されていた状態です。  
8ではなく7を指定しているのは参考にしたサイトそのままにしたからです。`-march=native`にすると`armv8-a+crc+simd`になるのですが、これを指定しても7を指定した時と同じ結果になっています。

Comment: 一本の(なるべく小さな)ソースファイルをコンパイル, ライブラリーとリンクすれば確実にエラーになるものがあれば, (そのソースを提示できれば)確認しやすいでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

落ちる原因の詳細を調べたいなら話は別だけれど
コンパイルしターゲットで動かすだけなら, あまり詳細なオプション付けないほうがよいかもしれません
(動作の違いで齟齬が出るよりも)

以下のパッケージで `x86_64` 環境での開発・実行を確認しています
(落ちる問題がこれで解決するかどうかは不明)

- `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf`
- `qemu-user`

```bash
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc testprog.c -static -o testprog
$ file testprog
testprog: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, BuildID[sha1]=da4bf261b887c6b54de4cfdb8bac483027593edd, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
$ qemu-arm testprog
```

※ 実機でも確認済み
手元の Raspberry Pi 4 は 64bit環境なので, static linkで行い・転送し動作確認した

g++ を利用するなら `g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf` パッケージ使用することになるでしょう

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。クロスコンパイル自体は動作確認までできています。ただ、実機でビルドする時と異なるオプションを付けないとコンパイルできない+ライブラリと実行ファイルでアーキテクチャが異なると動作しない、でやりたいようにできない状態でした。
ターゲットを纏めてビルドするプロジェクトを作って作業するようにしました。

Comment: この回答は, (そのための) **異なるオプションを指定せず**にすむ方法を示してます